# Like operator in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

how to check the reverse of the original word using like operator? For Eg: victoria state------state victoria

This is the query i tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.name) t1.gid,t1.name,t1.the_geom,t2.gid,t2.name,t2.the_geom 
FROM all_poi AS t1 
JOIN all_poi AS t2 ON ST_Dwithin(t1.the_geom,t2.the_geom,(0.005/111.111)) 
WHERE t1.gid != t2.gid and t1.name=t2.name and t1.name like'%%' 
ORDER BY t1.name, t1.gid,t2.gid,t2.name,t2.the_geom;
```

Comment: You forgot to show what you want to compare to what.

Answer (score 2):

The LIKE operator can't do this. No built-in function does what you are trying to do. Write a stored function, or make this transformation in the application code.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.name) t1.gid,t1.name,t1.the_geom,t2.gid,t2.name,t2.the_geom FROM all_poi AS t1  JOIN all_poi AS t2  ON ST_Dwithin(t1.the_geom,t2.the_geom,(0.005/111.111))   where t1.gid != t2.gid  and t1.name=t2.name and t1.name like'%%' ORDER BY t1.name, t1.gid,t2.gid,t2.name,t2.the_geom;



this query i tried

Comment: Ok, this is what you need, but not what you asked for. Reading your query, I realize that I had none of the information I needed to help you. Try to ask better, next time :)